# How to separate repetitive numbers

Tags: matlab, matrix, filtering, subset, rows

I have this kind of data

```
A = [1   0.5
     1   0.1
     1   0.3
     2   1
     2   0.5
     2   0.1
     2   1
     5   2  ]
```

Looking at the first column, there can be repeating numbers, and those appearing only once. From rows starting with repeating numbers, I want to select the last occurrence, along with the rest of the row. For the above example, my output will become:

```
Output = [1  0.3
          2  1  ]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: By "last" you mean "first"? So which is it, `0.5` or `0.3`? The example doesn't fit the description - please make sure they're consistent.

Comment: And what about the "5" in the first column?

Comment: Sorry. I already edit the output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume a couple of things:

1. The first column doesn't have to be sorted, but only contiguous groups are considered (i.e. if the first column contains entries like `[2;2;2;3;2]`, the last row won't be considered a part of the "`2` group"). If you want detached rows/groups to be considered, make sure to [sort the rows](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) of `A` before applying this algorithm).
2. The first column contains integers only.

Here's my suggestion:

```
out = A( [false; diff([logical(diff(A(:,1),1)); true])>0], :);
```

An explanation of the way it works:

- We differentiate the first column to detect value transitions.
- To the end of the previous result we concatenate a `true`, so that if the last row is part of a group, it gets considered.
- Then we differentiate this again, so that we detect consecutive transitions (like the `2->5` in your example. We keep only "positive" transitions because only this indicates a new number in the first column.
- Finally, we concatenate a `false` to the beginning, because the first row is never selected.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html#bs_6vpd-1-occurrence) function, you can easily solve your problem:

```
 %%% Find the first indices of the unique numbers in column 1
 [~, i_first, ~] = unique(A(:,1),'first');

 %%% Then, find the last indices of the unique numbers in column 1
 [~, i_last, ~] = unique(A(:,1),'last');

 %%% Lastly, remove the entries with the same starting and finishing index
 %%% from the last indices vector
 i_last(i_last == i_first) = [];

 %%% Output the requested values
 Output = A(i_last, :);
```

This solution asumes the following: (courtesy of [Dev-iL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3372061/dev-il))
 1.  first column has to contain integers (otherwise this would require uniquetol)
 2. non-contiguous groups are treated as contiguous (i.e. this performs sorting implicitly)

Comment: This is a good approach, though you might want to list the assumptions and features of your solution: 1) first column has to contain integers (otherwise this would require `uniquetol`); 2) non-contiguous groups are treated as contiguous (i.e. this performs sorting implicitly).

Comment: sure :) Don't forget you can [edit] your posts when needed.